# How to run RMI in netbeans in windows 7

Tags: java, rmi

Hello I am new to RMI in Java. I am using netbeans 6.9 and windows 7. I have simple rmi server and rmi client but dont know how to run them. I am writing in comand prompt start rmiregistry 1099 and also this port is used in the program. After I am just running the server and the error is

ava.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Can you tell me what is the sequence of actions to run simple RMI Server. I looked over many tutorials but cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing in comand prompt start rmiregistry 1099 and also this port is used in the program.

You can't do that. If you want to use the same port for the Registry and your own remote objects you have to start the Registry inside the same JVM, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your steps I think. But maybe in your server code you are trying to start rmiregistry again thus you face with this exception. Try not to start rmiregistry with command and just run server.

Also do you use any plugins from NetBeans?

If you can show us the server code we might be help a little more.